# Win Server 2K8 - Setting up SMTP Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, smtp

I'm setting up an SMTP server behind NAT. I'm a bit confused about the DNS requirements as I thought I could just setup the SMTP server and allow connections from the internal IP address on the machine and it would send out emails fine.

Now, I can get it sending emails to gmail accounts, but on other email accounts it seems to not be able to connect to their mail server.

I've read something about reverse DNS lookups - do I need to put in place some DNS records for a domain so the other mail servers can do a reverse lookup and check that I'm legit?
Currently, the emails just come from the external IP address of the server.

**Update**

The email sending problem has been identified as being non-standard line-endings in text only email. Make sure you use `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"` in text emails as some mail servers will reject your messages otherwise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second what DrStalker said, a lot of ISPs will block :25 to stop people from doing exactly what you're doing "For security purposes", but most will also lift it if you ask them to.

The other thing you need to look at are your MX Records in your DNS. The MX (or Mail eXchanger) record tells the mail servers where to deliver mail, as most mail servers are NOT on the web server.

For example, your web server is on `x.x.x.1` and your mail server is on `x.x.x.2`. Your A record for `www.example.com` points to `x.x.x.1` - great for web browsers, but not so great for delivering mail. To get around this, you create an MX record for www.example.com that points to `x.x.x.2`.

A few things to note for an MX record:

1. It MUST point to an A record for a Fully Qualified Domain Name
2. It CANNOT point to a CNAME
3. It CANNOT point to an IP address

So, you might set up an A record for `mail.example.com` and point it to `x.x.x.2` and your MX for `example.com` to `mail.example.com`.

Has your head exploded yet?

It's worth noting that this method is only required if your Mail Server and your Web Server are on different public IP addresses. If they're on the same public IP and you just forward you mail based on the port at the router, then you don't **need** to do it. However, it's **very good practice** to have an MX for every domain you expect to receive mail for, even if you just point it to the A record for your zone.

Your query regarding Reverse DNS is only applicable for when you are sending mail. If you are able to send to gmail.com chances are that you're fine (most commercial or residential IP addresses have a reverse DNS configured, it just points to a PTR record on the ISP's DNS), and that it's got nothing to do with receiving mail.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far. My situation is that I've got 1 web server with a whole bunch of small sites on it. Each site has it's own domain with an A record pointing at the IP of the server.

The thing is - I can send to Google Apps accounts and gmail addresses fine - it's just one address I can't send to from the server. If I email that person it's fine. So I'm not really receiving email for anyone, just sending it out from websites. Could their ISP be trying to authenticate who I am and not allow it through?

Comment: Aah, I follow. Yes, that can happen, but usually your email would end up in their junk mail. It might be in your interests to contact the provider to find out which anti-spam service they use so that you can find out why your emails are failing.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you need to do.  I'm not sure why it would work to gmail and not elsewhere; exactly how many different domains have you tried sending to?

1) Check your SMTP logs.  Enable logging if it's not enabled (use IIS Admin).

2) Make sure that you can resolve locally the mail domains you can't send to.

3) Try running telnet to port 25 on the server(s) you cannot connect to.  It's easy enough to manually send an email using this method.

NOTE: checking your logs can eliminate the need for 2 & 3 usually.

4) Enabling reverse DNS will require that you contact your ISP and have them configure it for you.  This is definitely a criterion by which mail servers / spam filters will reject email, although it's not universal.

5) If you've got any sort of firewalls that filters SMTP, disable them (even check your internet router, especially if it's Cisco).

6) Make sure that you've setup SMTP correctly: http://www.itsolutionskb.com/2008/11/installing-and-configuring-windows-server-2008-smtp-server/

Comment: This is the error message I get:

"This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Unable to deliver message to the following recipients, due to being unable to connect successfully to the destination mail server."

Their email address which I'm trying to send to recieves email fine when you send it normally through an email client, but for some reason fails when sending it via this website. Could their email host be rejected the connection attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Does your ISP allow you to send out SMTP traffic?  a lot of ISPs block this; to check try manually connecting to the remote server on port 25.  If that doesn't work you need to either get the ISP to open outbound SMTP traffic, or configure you SMTP server to relay mail through the ISP's SMTP server.

Comment: Yes, it appears the hosting company does allow outbound SMTP traffic - as I can send to Google Apps, Gmail accounts fine.